# Odoo 10 Dynamic Filtering

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10, listview-filter

Ok, so I'm trying to make a couple of dynamic filters for hr_attendances.  I want to do something similar to 'current month' but I want current pay period (two week pay period) and previous pay period.  is there a simple way to do this? here is my current code. Is there either a way to reference the the fields from the config settings in the xml to make the domain completely in the xml or is there a way to use the methods I have defined below in HrAttendance?  I also have a cron job setting the fields in settings that runs every day.  Again, is there an easier way to run this?  The last question, is there a way to make these filters with JavaScript that is easier than what I'm currently looking at?

Settings:

```
class BaseConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'base.config.settings'

    previous_pay_period_start = fields.Datetime(string='Beginning of previous Pay Period')
    previous_pay_period_end = fields.Datetime(string='End of previous Pay Period')
    current_pay_period_start = fields.Datetime(string='Beginning of current Pay Period')
    current_pay_period_end = fields.Datetime(string='End of current Pay Period')

    @api.model
    def set_pay_periods(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        set_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param
        today = datetime.today()
        today = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        #set beginning of current week
        start_current_week = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday()+1)
        #empty variable to contain the beginning of the current pay period
        current_start_date = ''
        #Date which
        original_pay_period_start_date = datetime(2018, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0)
        if (((start_current_week - original_pay_period_start_date).days/7)%2) == 0:
            current_start_date = start_current_week
        else:
            current_start_date = start_current_week - timedelta(weeks=1)
        set_param('timeclock.previous_pay_period_start', (current_start_date - timedelta(weeks=2)))
        set_param('timeclock.previous_pay_period_end', (current_start_date - timedelta(days=1)))
        set_param('timeclock.current_pay_period_start', (current_start_date))
        set_param('timeclock.current_pay_period_end', (current_start_date + timedelta(weeks=2) - timedelta(days=1)))

    @api.model
    def get_default_pay_periods(self, fields):
        return self.get_pay_periods()

    @api.model
    def get_pay_periods(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        get_param =  self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param
        return {
            'previous_pay_period_start': get_param('timeclock.previous_pay_period_start', 'False'),
            'previous_pay_period_end': get_param('timeclock.previous_pay_period_end', 'False'),
            'current_pay_period_start': get_param('timeclock.current_pay_period_start', 'False'),
            'current_pay_period_end': get_param('timeclock.current_pay_period_end', 'False'),
        }
```

Hr_Attendance

```
class HrAttendance(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.attendance"

    @api.model
    def current_pay_period(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        settings = self.env['base.config.settings'].get_pay_periods()
        current_pay_period_start = settings['current_pay_period_start']
        current_pay_period_end = settings['current_pay_period_end']
        return [('check_in', '>=', current_pay_period_start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)), ('check_in', '<=', current_pay_period_end.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))]

    @api.model
    def previous_pay_period(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        settings = self.env['base.config.settings'].get_pay_periods()
        previous_pay_period_start = settings['previous_pay_period_start']
        previous_pay_period_end = settings['previous_pay_period_end']
        return [('check_in', '>=', previous_pay_period_start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)), ('check_in', '<=', previous_pay_period_end.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))]
```

And the XML

```
<record id="hr_attendance_filter_emp_locs" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">hr.attendance.filter.emp_locs</field>
  <field name="model">hr.attendance</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_attendance.hr_attendance_view_filter"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//filter[@name='groupby_name']" position="after">
      <filter name="location" string="Location" context="{'group_by': 'location_id'}"/>
      <filter name="zone" string="Zone" context="{'group_by': 'zone_id'}"/>
      <field name="job_id"/>
    </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//filter[@name='today']" position="before">
      <filter string="Current Pay Period" domain="current_pay_period()" />
      <filter string="Last Pay Period" domain="previous_pay_period()" />
    </xpath>

  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Please ask one question; you are asking 3.  Also, for each please describe clearly what you are trying to achieve what you have tried and what does not work as desired.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a single problem and asking for advice on how to solve it.  The problem is setting up dynamic filters based on pay period.  The rest is my thoughts on the process.

Comment: I see... I think I did something once with overriding the search method and modify the domain on the fly, replacing a symbolic keyword that you can put on the right-hand side of a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with some help.  Here is my working answer.

```
@api.model
def search(self, args, limit=None, offset=0, order=None, count=False):
    pay_periods = self.env['base.config.settings'].get_pay_periods()
    if self.env.context.get('current_pay_period', False):
        args += [('check_in', '>=', pay_periods['current_pay_period_start']),
                ('check_in', '<=', pay_periods['current_pay_period_end'])]
    if self.env.context.get('previous_pay_period', False):
        args += [('check_in', '>=', pay_periods['previous_pay_period_start']),
                    ('check_in', '<=', pay_periods['previous_pay_period_end'])]
    return super(HrAttendance, self).search(args, limit=limit)
```